# Swagger documentation for Spring Pageable interface

Tags: json, spring, rest, swagger

I have developed a microservice using Spring Boot. The documentation for the REST API is made with Swagger. Some REST resources make use of Spring concepts to provide pagination for free. Below is an example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/buckets", method = GET)
public PagedResources list(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {
    return bucketService.listBuckets(pageable, assembler);
}
```

If I open the Swagger page, the following form is available for the resource:

[image]

The issue I have is that the pageable parameter is detected with content-type *application/json* and I don't know how to pass a value to change the page size for example. All values seem to be ignored.

Is it possible to pass the query parameters as JSON object? or is it possible to configure Swagger to generate independent query parameter fields for getters contained by the Pageable interface?

Please note that I am using Springfox with Gradle:

```
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:2.3.1'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.3.1'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.3.1'
```

Comment: Are you using spring-fox to generate the Swagger spec from the REST controller?

Comment: Yes, I am using Springfox in version _2.3.1_.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is a known issue with Spring-Fox. See Issue [#755](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/755). Based on zdila's comment [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v041.png) at this time alternative is to add @ApiImplicitParams which is not ideal but it does work.

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page", dataType = "integer", paramType = "query",
            value = "Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", dataType = "integer", paramType = "query",
            value = "Number of records per page."),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "sort", allowMultiple = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query",
            value = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). " +
                    "Default sort order is ascending. " +
                    "Multiple sort criteria are supported.")
})
```

[[image: Swagger UI showing @ApiImplicitParams for Pageable]]

[1](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/755) https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/755

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v041.png) https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/755#issuecomment-135059871

Comment: I found I had to use `dataType = "int"` otherwise the data type comes out as Undefined as shown in the picture.

Comment: It seems the issue has been fixed and the answer could consequentially be updated..

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967447/how-to-globally-ignore-api-of-spring-boot-from-open-api-3-specification?noredirect=1#comment106052889_59967447 ?

Comment: any solution for springdoc?

Answer (score 23):

Building on Vineet Bhatia's answer, you can wrap the solution up in a custom annotation for reusability:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page", dataType = "int", paramType = "query", value = "Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", dataType = "int", paramType = "query", value = "Number of records per page."),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "sort", allowMultiple = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query", value = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). "
            + "Default sort order is ascending. " + "Multiple sort criteria are supported.") })
@interface ApiPageable {
}
```

Which can then be used like so:

```
@ApiPageable
public Page<Data> getData(Pageable pageRequest) {
```

Comment: This can't work like this.

`'ApiImplicitParams' not applicable to annotation type`

Comment: Worked just fine for version 2.8.0

Comment: Make sure to use `@ApiIgnore` annotation to the `Pageable` parameter.

Comment: @Sean - How can we configure Pagination for the OpenAPI 3 or Swagger 3 ?

Comment: @PAA what did you try? It would be a good contribution to the community if you figured it.

Comment: @SeanConnolly he put his version in a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058976/open-api-3-how-to-read-spring-boot-pagination-properties

Answer (score 11):

Vineet Bhatia's answer with `@ApiImplicitParams` looks fine. But I faced with situation, when `@ApiIgnor` and `@ApiParam(hidden = true)` doesn't work and you can still observe the asembler and pageable params. I fixed this problem by adding next line

```
docket.ignoredParameterTypes(Pageable.class, PagedResourcesAssembler.class);
```

to the Docket bean in my `SwaggerConfig`.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't works with the SpringDocs-openapi-ui. Any guidance how to make it work ?

Answer (score 10):

Java example:

Bean:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .directModelSubstitute(Pageable.class, SwaggerPageable.class);
}
```

SwaggerPageable:

```
@Getter
private static class SwaggerPageable {

    @ApiParam(value = "Number of records per page", example = "0")
    @Nullable
    private Integer size;

    @ApiParam(value = "Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)", example = "0")
    @Nullable
    private Integer page;

    @ApiParam(value = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). Default sort order is ascending. Multiple sort criteria are supported.")
    @Nullable
    private String sort;

}
```

Swagger:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Open API 3.0 has seamless integration.

For example,

```
@GetMapping("/filter")
public Page<Employee> filterEmployees(Pageable pageable) {
     return repository.getEmployees(pageable);
}
```

Add springdoc-openapi-data-rest dependency

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest:1.5.2'
```

Note: You may add '**@ParameterObject**' if you have multiple parameters

```
public Page<Employee> filterEmployees(@ParameterObject Pageable pageable)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is the version of the annotation that was integrated into springdoc-openapi-data-rest for OpenAPI v3:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY
        , description = "Zero-based page index (0..N)"
        , name = "page"
        , content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "integer", defaultValue = "0")))
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY
        , description = "The size of the page to be returned"
        , name = "size"
        , content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "integer", defaultValue = "20")))
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY
        , description = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). "
        + "Default sort order is ascending. " + "Multiple sort criteria are supported."
        , name = "sort"
        , content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(type = "string"))))
public @interface PageableAsQueryParam {

}
```

Use example:

```
@GetMapping("/page")
@PageableAsQueryParam
public Page<Account> findAll(@Parameter(hidden=true) Pageable pageable) {
    return accountRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

See [SpringDoc FAQ](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#_how_can_i_map_pageable_spring_data_commons_object_to_correct_url_parameter_in_swagger_ui).

Comment: Could you please guide me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834165/spring-open-api-specification-3-array-property-names-has-to-be-pluralized-co

Comment: Is there any way to send query parameters in single Parameter ?

Answer (score 5):

This solution works without the need to annotate every single API method in every single controller. First we create a replacement for `Pageable` class with the correct property names and descriptions (Kotlin code, you can use a Interface for Java):

```
data class SwaggerPageable(
        @ApiModelProperty("Number of records per page", example = "20")
        val size: Int?,

        @ApiModelProperty("Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)", example = "0")
        val page: Int?,

        @ApiModelProperty("Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc)." +
                "Default sort order is ascending. Multiple sort criteria are supported.")
        var sort: String?
)
```

Then in the Swagger config, just add a direct substitute from `Pageable` to this class (again Kotlin code, but Java should be pretty similar):

```
@Bean
fun api(): Docket {
    return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .directModelSubstitute(Pageable::class.java, SwaggerPageable::class.java)
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The downside is not being able to define the default value in the `ApiModelProperty`, but this is more than good enough for my project.

Comment: How can we use Pageable in Open API 3 version?

Answer (score 4):

Answer of Vineet Bhatia will have validation problem when you are not running on localhost. It will argue for integer parameters that they are not corresponding to json schema.

So I changed integer to string:

```
    @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page", dataType = "string", paramType = "query",
                value = "Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", dataType = "string", paramType = "query",
                value = "Number of records per page."),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "sort", allowMultiple = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query",
                value = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). " +
                        "Default sort order is ascending. " +
                        "Multiple sort criteria are supported.")
})
```

Answer (score 3):

For people who wants to solve this problem in 2019. This configuration via [springfox documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#creating-a-convention) works fine except you can't set description for parameters.

Code is here.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/ef1721afc4c910675d9032bee59aea8e75e06d27/springfox-data-rest/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/spring/data/rest/configuration/SpringDataRestConfiguration.java

Comment: with this class I get the following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: @mor222 - you can remove RepositoryRestConfiguration altogether and replace `restConfiguration.getPageParamName()` with "page", `restConfiguration.getLimitParamName()` with "size" and `restConfiguration.getSortParamName()` with "sort" respectively

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution for springdoc-openapi-ui

```
SpringDocUtils.getConfig()
.replaceWithClass(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.class, SwaggerPageable.class);
    
@Getter
private static class SwaggerPageable {
    
        @ApiParam(value = "Number of records per page", example = "0")
        @Nullable
        private Integer size;
    
        @ApiParam(value = "Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)", example = "0")
        @Nullable
        private Integer page;
    
        @ApiParam(value = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). Default sort order is ascending. Multiple sort criteria are supported.")
        @Nullable
        private String sort;
    
}
```

Comment: Hey! The question already has answers which cover both spring fox and spring doc openapi, so your answer doesn’t add more information. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Moritz Hey. Would you be so kind and point out that answer. I was looking for it and had to dig out the SpringDocUtils.getConfig()
.replaceWithClass(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.class, SwaggerPageable.class); 
port  from a github discussin (@ApiImplicitParams is not the only solution)..

Comment: oh... and... I don't have enough stars to add comments to other posts so this was the only way I could bing that line up. Feel free to use my finding add a comment to some other post. I'll be happy to remove my answer

Answer (score 1):

An update:

Use `org.springdoc.core.converters.models.DefaultPageable` instead of `Pageable`. It already has the `@ParameterObject` which makes it breakdown in to 3 parameters when the Swagger JSON is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to validation problem indicated by Evgeny.

Using

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page", dataType = "int", paramType = "query", value = "Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", dataType = "int", paramType = "query", value = "Number of records per page."),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "sort", allowMultiple = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query", value = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). "
            + "Default sort order is ascending. " + "Multiple sort criteria are supported.") })
```

throws an exception:

```
Illegal DefaultValue  for parameter type integer
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:709)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1151)
    at io.swagger.models.parameters.AbstractSerializableParameter.getExample(AbstractSerializableParameter.java:412)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)
```

(at least, it does with springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger2-ui version 2.9.2)

You can avoid the exception by following Evgeny's answer or by adding default values and example values for the integer parameters:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page", dataType = "int", paramType = "query", value = "Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)", defaultValue = "0", example = "2"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", dataType = "int", paramType = "query", value = "Number of records per page.", defaultValue = "20", example = "10"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "sort", allowMultiple = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query", value = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). "
            + "Default sort order is ascending. " + "Multiple sort criteria are supported.") })
```

Answer (score -1):

Although the solution with the implicit parameters works, it introduces a lot of extra, brittle code. In the end we went with the following solution:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
public HttpEntity<PagedResources<Item>> getItems(
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
    @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size,
    PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {
    Page<Item> itemPage = itemService.listItems(PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.unsorted()));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(assembler.toResource(itemPage), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

We pass a `PageRequest` (which implements `Pageable`) to our service, which returns a `Page`. (all from `org.springframework.data.domain`).

The `org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler` gets injected automagically via the controller method and allows mapping Items to `org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources`

We didn't require dynamic sorting so we omitted that; it poses some challenges to add sorting since springfox does not play nice with org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.